# Is the context below atomic in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, spinlock

```
spin_lock_irqsave(...);

spin_unlock(...);
/* context */
spin_lock(...);

spin_unlock_irqrestore(...);
```

Is the context mentioned in above example atomic ? Here, we are just disabling the interrupts not preemption I guess.

Comment: I do not understand the question? There is not a useful *context* to answer your question; you have just lock/unlock spinlocks in a wrong way

Comment: The code could be running on multiple processors/cores

Comment: *Atomic* by necessity avoids locks.  The spinlock is a non-atomic way of doing the same thing.  You have some mixed up nomenclature.  Did you mean to do the exact sequence you have?  It seems that things are not locked at *context* and therefore you have race conditions under any situation.  Interrupts can be pre-emptive.  Look at [`atomic_inc()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=atomic_inc), etc for real atomic primitives.

Comment: Given sequence is also acceptable and you can find them in open source drivers. Here we are just trying to release the lock and acquiring back. This is usally called whenever there is a need to call a callback function which you do not have any idea what it does. Assume code is running on SMP processor.